# ZF2. Do I always need to return a ViewModel from action?

Tags: zend-framework2

As of right ow - each of my actions must have some ViewModel that it returns, ex:

```
$viewModel = new ViewModel();
return $viewModel;
```

But what if in some cases I simply assign value to layout's content variable like this:

```
$content = 'blah blah some content';
$this->layout()->setVariable('content', $content);
```

So - AFAIk - in this case I don't really need to return a ViewModel - right? -as Layout's content already populated.. However -if I don't - ZF2 injects one automatically and I get an error about non-existing template..... Any thiugths on how to avoid returning ViewModel?

Comment: Question: why have a action that only changes the layout? Especially your example makes absolutely no sense as the content ARE the action-templates...

Comment: @Sam what is you have preexisting model or remote service that returns text instead of a ZF2 viewmodel. Then you need to use that text instead of simply returning a view model.  I can create an empty viewmodel of course and assign text to it - that's just not very clean....

Answer (score 4):

You could

```
return $this->getResponse();
```

This will result in not requiring any file.phtml to be returned.